# How to parse json format output of : kubectl get pods using jsonpath

Tags: json, parsing, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

How to parse the json to retrieve a field from output of

```
kubectl get pods -o json
```

From the command line I need to obtain the system generated container name from a google cloud cluster ...  Here are the salient bits of json output from above command :
[image]

[click here to see entire json output](https://gist.github.com/scottstensland/278ce94dc6873aa54e44)

So the top most json key is an array : items[] followed by metadata.labels.name where the search critera value of that compound key is "web"  (see above image green marks).  On a match, I then need to retrieve field

```
.items[].metadata.name
```

which so happens to have value :

```
web-controller-5e6ij   // I need to retrieve this value
```

[Here are docs on jsonpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/)

I want to avoid text parsing output of

```
kubectl get pods
```

which is

```
NAME                     READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongo-controller-h714w   1/1       Running   0          12m
web-controller-5e6ij     1/1       Running   0          9m
```

Following will correctly parse this `get pods` command yet I feel its too fragile

```
kubectl get pods | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After much battling this one liner does retrieve the container name :

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.labels.name=="web")].metadata.name}'
```

when this is the known search criteria :

```
items[].metadata.labels.name  == "web"
```

and this is the desired field to retrieve

```
items[].metadata.name  :  "web-controller-5e6ij"
```

Answer (score 21):

If you want to filter by labels. You could just use the `kubectl -l` flag. The following will do the same:

```
kubectl get pods -l name=web -o=jsonpath='{.items..metadata.name}'
```

Comment: No one mentioned about having `..` to print an array. Quite helpful!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Scott Stensland answer, a way to format your results:

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.metadata.labels.name=="web")]}{.metadata.name}{"/n"}'
```

This add newlines. You can also do {", "} to output comma with space.

**Another solution:**

Use JQ to get a nicely formatted json result:

```
kubectl get pods -o json | jq -r '.items[] | [filter] | [formatted result]' | jq -s '.'
```

Example of [filter]:

```
select(.metadata.labels.name=="web")
```

Example of [formatted result] (you can add more fields if your want):

```
{name: .metadata.name}
```

jq -s '.', for putting result objects in array.

To wrap it up:

```
kubectl get pods -o json | jq -r '.items[] | select(.metadata.labels.name=="web") | {name: .metadata.name}' | jq -s '.'
```

Then afterwards you can use this json data to get the desired output result.

Comment: You're missing `{end}` with your use of `range`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a super easy way to do this with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Just pipe your output with parameters you have already given.

As your searched value is positioned as second, please put index in brackets. No index given, means list all fitting.

```
<output> | jq .items[1].metadata.name
```

Example you have given ( i have put -r for raw output with no quotation)

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/scottstensland/278ce94dc6873aa54e44/raw/b2fc423bc4063a7cd16825f612e19d9a7faf5699/output%2520of%2520kubectl%2520get%2520pods%2520%2520-o%2520json| jq .items[1].metadata.name -r
web-controller-5e6ij
```